# DLL not found when Debugg using Windbg for Windows7

Tags: windows, dll, windows-7, windbg

When I try to debug program using Windbg in Windows7,always met with Error below(symbol prompts on)

```
Microsoft (R) Windows Debugger Version 6.12.0002.633 AMD64
Copyright (c) Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.

CommandLine: E:\Project\Exploitment2\x64\Debug\Exploitment2.exe
Symbol search path is: srv*C:\Symbols*https://msdl.microsoft.com/download/symbols;C:\symbols;SRV*C:\Symbols*http://msdl.microsoft.com/download/symbols
Executable search path is: 
ModLoad: 00000001`3f550000 00000001`3f55b000   Exploitment2.exe
ModLoad: 00000000`77030000 00000000`771cf000   ntdll.dll
ModLoad: 00000000`76e10000 00000000`76f2f000   C:\Windows\system32\kernel32.dll
ModLoad: 000007fe`fd2c0000 000007fe`fd32a000   C:\Windows\system32\KERNELBASE.dll
ModLoad: 000007fe`f09a0000 000007fe`f09c3000   C:\Windows\system32\VCRUNTIME140D.dll
ModLoad: 000007fe`f07e0000 000007fe`f0999000   C:\Windows\system32\ucrtbased.dll
ModLoad: 000007fe`f9930000 000007fe`f9933000   C:\Windows\system32\api-ms-win-core-timezone-l1-1-0.dll
ModLoad: 000007fe`f94b0000 000007fe`f94b3000   C:\Windows\system32\api-ms-win-core-file-l2-1-0.dll
ModLoad: 000007fe`f94a0000 000007fe`f94a3000   C:\Windows\system32\api-ms-win-core-localization-l1-2-0.dll
ModLoad: 000007fe`f9490000 000007fe`f9493000   C:\Windows\system32\api-ms-win-core-synch-l1-2-0.dll
ModLoad: 000007fe`f9480000 000007fe`f9483000   C:\Windows\system32\api-ms-win-core-processthreads-l1-1-1.dll
ModLoad: 000007fe`f9470000 000007fe`f9473000   C:\Windows\system32\api-ms-win-core-file-l1-2-0.dll
ModLoad: 000007fe`fea80000 000007fe`feb5b000   C:\Windows\system32\ADVAPI32.dll
ModLoad: 000007fe`feb60000 000007fe`febff000   C:\Windows\system32\msvcrt.dll
ModLoad: 000007fe`fec00000 000007fe`fec1f000   C:\Windows\SYSTEM32\sechost.dll
ModLoad: 000007fe`fedd0000 000007fe`feefc000   C:\Windows\system32\RPCRT4.dll
(94c.934): Break instruction exception - code 80000003 (first chance)
.........
SYMSRV:  c:\symbols\Exploitment2.pdb\E57EDA97746F448B856ADFEFBEA7C0141\Exploitment2.pdb not found
SYMSRV:  https://msdl.microsoft.com/download/symbols/Exploitment2.pdb/E57EDA97746F448B856ADFEFBEA7C0141/Exploitment2.pdb not found
DBGHELP: c:\symbols\Exploitment2.pdb - file not found
DBGHELP: c:\symbols\exe\Exploitment2.pdb - file not found
DBGHELP: c:\symbols\symbols\exe\Exploitment2.pdb - file not found
SYMSRV:  c:\symbols\Exploitment2.pdb\E57EDA97746F448B856ADFEFBEA7C0141\Exploitment2.pdb not found
SYMSRV:  http://msdl.microsoft.com/download/symbols/Exploitment2.pdb/E57EDA97746F448B856ADFEFBEA7C0141/Exploitment2.pdb not found
DBGHELP: Exploitment2 - private symbols & lines 
         E:\Project\Exploitment2\x64\Debug\Exploitment2.pdb
SYMSRV:  c:\symbols\kernel32.pdb\FDF36D27D20A4A47A72E7AF0FD70DA412\kernel32.pdb not found
SYMSRV:  https://msdl.microsoft.com/download/symbols/kernel32.pdb/FDF36D27D20A4A47A72E7AF0FD70DA412/kernel32.pdb not found
DBGHELP: c:\symbols\kernel32.pdb - file not found
DBGHELP: c:\symbols\dll\kernel32.pdb - file not found
DBGHELP: c:\symbols\symbols\dll\kernel32.pdb - file not found
SYMSRV:  c:\symbols\kernel32.pdb\FDF36D27D20A4A47A72E7AF0FD70DA412\kernel32.pdb not found
SYMSRV:  http://msdl.microsoft.com/download/symbols/kernel32.pdb/FDF36D27D20A4A47A72E7AF0FD70DA412/kernel32.pdb not found
DBGHELP: C:\Windows\system32\kernel32.pdb - file not found
DBGHELP: kernel32.pdb - file not found
*** ERROR: Symbol file could not be found.  Defaulted to export symbols for C:\Windows\system32\kernel32.dll - 
DBGHELP: kernel32 - export symbols
SYMSRV:  c:\symbols\ntdll.pdb\0642F49FE33C4A35B76816A238FF86ED1\ntdll.pdb not found
SYMSRV:  https://msdl.microsoft.com/download/symbols/ntdll.pdb/0642F49FE33C4A35B76816A238FF86ED1/ntdll.pdb not found
DBGHELP: c:\symbols\ntdll.pdb - file not found
DBGHELP: c:\symbols\dll\ntdll.pdb - file not found
DBGHELP: c:\symbols\symbols\dll\ntdll.pdb - file not found
SYMSRV:  c:\symbols\ntdll.pdb\0642F49FE33C4A35B76816A238FF86ED1\ntdll.pdb not found
SYMSRV:  http://msdl.microsoft.com/download/symbols/ntdll.pdb/0642F49FE33C4A35B76816A238FF86ED1/ntdll.pdb not found
DBGHELP: C:\Windows\SYSTEM32\ntdll.pdb - file not found
DBGHELP: ntdll.pdb - file not found
*** ERROR: Symbol file could not be found.  Defaulted to export symbols for ntdll.dll - 
DBGHELP: ntdll - export symbols
```

I have tried to set 'Symbol File Path' to 'srv*C:\Symbols*[https://msdl.microsoft.com/download/symbols'](https://msdl.microsoft.com/download/symbols%27) then reload it and Internet is alright but error remains.
Also I tried to download symbol file directly but it seems microsoft no longer support offline download.
Any other ways to fix it?

Comment: Windows 7 reached end of life a while ago, so naturally Microsoft deleted obsolete bits. If you want to do something interesting, do it on Windows 10/11.

Comment: @LexLi They deleted dlls/pdbs from the symbol server? I hope that's not true.

Comment: @LexLi: Is there an official statement about that? Well, they did it before with Windows XP, so it is certainly possible.

Comment: @ThomasWeller I don't think there is any official statement around the symbol server. You might refer to previous discussions to learn more https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46538218/microsoft-symbol-server-deleting-old-content